# Installation showing only SQLite as database option

Tags: database, 8, installation

I using Windows 8.1, XAMPP 3.2.2 and Drupal 8.0.3.

When I install Drupal, it only gives an option for Database as SQLite and it stores the file in `drupal->sites->default->files`. Then inside the folder 'files' name of the SQLite DB is `drupal.ht.sqlite`.

I want to use MySQL as DB instead of sqlite, Please help me to get out of this problem. And I have add some content it is working fine.

Comment: Does phpMyAdmin work under your MAMP to connect to the local database server?  Are there any warnings on the **Verify Requirements** screen before you are asked for database credentials?  If you add a simple file with just `<?php phpinfo()` in it, do you see MySQL entries?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Dear MPD I have mention in my query that I am using xampp. I am not using mamp. And phpmyadmin is working fine.

Comment: Please don't add the Drupal version in the title; we have the [tag:8] tag for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have the `pdo-sql` PHP module activated if you want to use MySQL, otherwise the MySQL option will not appear. For more details, see [no mysql option at install](https://www.drupal.org/node/2219779).

Comment: You are the man dinopmi. Thanks a lot and lots of hugs. Problem solved. And name of the extension in 'php.ini' file is 'extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll'.

Comment: You are welcome! If your problem was solved, don't forget to mark one of the two answers you received as "accepted" (Clive's answer was essentially the same as mine, but more detailed). Like that, your question will not be listed in the "Unanswered" section anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to convert an existing site as far as I know; you'll need to build a new site and migrate the content over to it. It might be easier to just start a new site from scratch and export/import the data manually, depending on how far you've got.

Before you do that, you need to enable MySQL in PHP. If you only see SQLite as a DB option, it means you haven't installed the PDO MySQL extension. Consult your web server's documentation for instructions on how to do that.

Once you have, MySQL will appear as an option for installation.